# Initial Value Problem using Laplace transformation: What is the ${\cal L}$ transform of $u(t-5)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I'm solving past exam questions in preparation for an Applied Mathematics course. I came to the following exercise, which poses a single difficulty. *If it's any indication of difficulty, the exercise is only Part 2-B of the sheet, graded for 10%*

> Solve the following initial value problem using Laplace transformation:
>   $y''(t)+6y'(t)+5y(t)=u(t-5)$ with $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$
>   The exercise also gives a table for Laplace transformations, and notably: ${\cal L}\{ u(t-a)f(t-a)\} = e^{-ts}F(s), a\geq 0$

I understand that $u(t-5)$ is the unit step function, but what is its ${\cal L}$ transform?

If I begin getting the transforms, I get ${\cal L}\{ y''\} + 6{\cal L}\{ y'\} +5{\cal L}\{ y \} = {\cal L}\{ u(t-5)\}$

The first part of the equation poses no problem, but I do not know how to transform the unit step function, and I can't use the given transformation in the exercise notes as I do not have a $f(t-a)$ next to it.

Comment: if you have difficulties computing $\int_5^\infty e^{-st} dt$ then you'll have some problems

Comment: Write down the definition of the Laplace transform.

Comment: and $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-a) f(t-a)\} = e^{-as} F(s)$ where $F(s) = \mathcal{L}\{u(t) f(t)\} $ this is known as the shift theorem